# Calculating Parameters for extrapolation curve using Gompertz and Gamma using Flexsurv

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

I'm computing some extrapolation curves for a pharmacoeconomic analysis and I'm struggling to get the parameters of the curve for Gompertz and Gamma.
I'm using flexsurv

```
mgomp1 <- flexsurvreg(Surv(times_start, times_end, type="interval2") ~ 1,
                  dist ="gompertz")
mgamma <- flexsurvreg(Surv(times_start, times_end, type="interval2") ~ 1, 
                  dist ="gengamma")
```

And I get for Gompertz:

```
> coef(mgomp1)
    shape      rate 
 0.001000 -7.207298
```

And for Gamma:

```
> coef(mgamma)
          mu        sigma            Q 
 1.515808635 -0.195512114 -0.006103075
```

How can I get two parameters for Gompertz (Theta and lambda) curve and 3 parameters for Gamma curve?
I'm missing some procedure to get the curve parameters.

Additional:

I'm trying to build curve in Excel:
For Gamma, using the netx formula:

```
=IF($K$4>0, 1-GAMMA.DIST.N((1/$K$4^2)* 
 EXP(-$K$5)*B13)^($K$4/$K$3),1/$K$4^2,1,TRUE),GAMMA.DIST.N((
  1/$K$4^2)*EXP(-$K$5)*B13)^($K$4/$K$3),1/$K$4^2,1,TRUE))
```

And for Gompertz:

```
=EXP(-$L$4/$L$3*(EXP($L$3*B13)-1))
```

For others distributions, like exponential, I've used coefficients transformations, for example:

```
exp(-(summary(model)$table[,1]))
```

To get the curve parameter and using the formula

```
(=EXP((-1/$H$42)*EXP($H$43)*(EXP($H$42*D50)-1)))
```

to model the curve on excel.
Hope this helps to make more clear my assistant request.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're seeking. When you say "how can I get two parameters for Gompertz (Theta and lambda) curve and 3 parameters for Gamma curve?" ... you do get two for Gompertz and three for gamma already. It's also not completely clear what you mean by "theta" and "lambda" unless you specify a parameterization where those parameters are defined.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b for you answer, I've added extra details to explain more about mi assistance request. Thank you.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.